# Best approach to post to a users Facebook page on behalf of application.

Tags: facebook, spring, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I understand the format of stackoverflow questions. My question is a little broad maybe, but I need help regarding what approach to use, I have done my research and things are getting confusing by day. Any help will be appreciated.

I have a web application(java, springs framework, spring social, also facebook JS sdk on UI for login screens) that has two type of users: **type 1** and **type 2**. Type 1 users are sort of like producers of content and Type 2 consumers. type 1 users can visit a type 2 profile and consume their content.

Now whenever a type 1 user consumes content from type 2, I want to publish that activity(as a story or a post) on a facebook page owned by the type 2 user on behalf of either (my application or a facebook user owned by me, who would have liked the type 2 users page)

I am trying to find the best approach or mode to do a thing like this for my application.

Initially open graph looked promising until, I found out that it is not possible to post OG story on a facebook page.

The problems that I am not very clear about:

1. Is it possible to post on behalf of an application to a facebook page that is liked by the admin of the facbeook application ?
2. Another approach, I could think of was at time of type 2
   registration, I ask them to link their account with facebook and
   provide page id that they want content posted to. At this moment, I
   fetch and store in database their access token (long term) and later
   post to their pages using their access tokens

**Issues that I have here:** Their access token will expire eventually, in at most 60 days, now how to renew that? because, I am not expecting them to login even ever again in worst case. But I want to be able to post content whenever a type 1 interacts with a type 2.

3. The third case, post on behalf of a my facebook user(i have username
   and password) who owns the application and also has liked the
   facebook page of type 2. In here, Is it possible to get the access
   token for my user using spring social facebook (on server side). I
   could run job on server side to exchange this token for a new one
   when the current token is about to expire.

Also, I feel that this should not be a unique case. So, could you share experience on which approach would be best followed in such a case(sort of like the standard case), who should post on whose wall. I just want to show the activity appear on type 2 users facebook page that "name of type 1 user" consumed content on my application.

Comment: The app can not post on a page. You can use a user or page access token to post on a page. You can not get an access token from username and password

Comment: @WizKid: Thanks for that. Also, is this true that page access tokens do not expire? Plus,  can a page post on another page?